# Como puedo resolver este problema de objetos usando for ... in

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

quisiera saber como puedo resolver este problema de Objetos de JS, utilizando el bucle for ... in, ya que lo intente pero no me estaría resultando. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que lo que te falta acceder a la propiedad "online"

```
if(usuarios[clave].online === true)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!